# How to implement a background worker thread queue

Tags: wpf, multithreading, mvvm, backgroundworker

I'm trying to implement my first application using the MVVM pattern. I've manged to get most things working, but now I'm facing a problem with the following (IMHO pretty common) scenario:

Pressing a `Button` (View) shall invoke a Method (Model). Using a `ICommand` (ViewModel) this is pretty easy.  But what to do if a time consuming operation has to be executed?

My current solution required me to implement a `WorkQueue` class containing `WorkQueueItems`. The `WorkQueue` has a Thread associated with it which executes the `WorkQueueItem`s. Each `WorkQueueItem` has a `Name`, a `Status` and a `Progress` which is updated during execution. 
Each `Window` has its own `WorkQueue` - visualized as `StatusBar`.

**My problem:** How can a ViewModel find the appropriate `WorkQueue`? Do I have to pass the `WorkQueue` to each ViewModel I create (this would be really be annoying)? Or are there other mechanism I could use?

I'm not really familiar with `RoutedCommand`s - tough the basic concept seems to go into this direction. What'd love to see is a solution where I can bind a `WorkQueueItem` to a Command/Event which then bubbles up to the containing `Window` where it is added to the `Window`'s `WorkQueue`.

I also considered making `WorkQueue` a Singleton - but this only works if I only have one `Window` at a time.

Comment: Which version of .Net? You may have access to [`System.Threading.Tasks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx).

Comment: .NET 4.0 or 4.5 no real limitations apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the later .Net Frameworks (4.0+) and WPF you can utilize the [`System.Threading.Tasks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx) library to provide a lot of this work under the hood.

If say your Command on your needs to update a property on your View Model, but it has to wait for the information, you simply start a task to perform the IO:

```
this.FindDataCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(
    /* ICommand.Execute */
    value =>
    {
        Task.Factory
            .StartNew<IEnumerable<Foo>>(() => FindData(value))
            .ContinueWith(
                task =>
                {
                    this.foundData.Clear();
                    this.foundData.AddRange(task.Result);
                },
                TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    },

    /* ICommand.CanExecute */
    value => !String.IsNullOrWhitespace(value));
```

Breaking this down into manageable parts, we're [starting a new task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321421.aspx) which calls some method `IEnumerable<Foo> FindData(string)`. This is the plain old boring synchronous code you've always written. Likely it already exists on your view model!

Next we tell the framework to [start a new task when that one finishes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) using `ContinueWith`, but to do it on the [WPF Dispatcher instead](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/4034). This allows you to avoid the hassles of cross-thread problems with UI elements.

You can extend this for monitoring with a helper class:

```
public class TaskManager
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<Dispatcher, TaskManager> _map
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<Dispatcher, TaskManager>();

    public ObservableCollection<WorkItem> Running
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public TaskManager()
    {
        this.Running = new ObservableCollection<WorkItem>();
    }

    public static TaskManager Get(Dispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        return _map.GetOrAdd(dispatcher, new TaskManager());
    }
    // ...
```

Using this class in XAML would be along the lines of adding its instance to your Window's `ViewModel`:

```
public TaskManager CurrentTaskManager
{
    get { return TaskManager.Get(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher); }
}
// <StatusBarItem Content="{Binding CurrentTaskManager.Running.Count}" />
```

You would then add a method to your TaskManager to handle the adding of tasks to and from the Running collection:

```
    public Task<TResult> StartNew<TResult>(Func<TResult> work)
    {
         var task = Task.Factory
                        .StartNew<TResult>(work);

         // build our view model
         var workItem = new WorkItem(task);
         this.Running.Add(workItem);

         // Pass the result back using ContinueWith
         return task.ContinueWith(
             t => { this.Running.Remove(workItem); return t.Result; },
             TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
```

Now we simply change our `FindDataCommand` implementation:

```
TaskManager.Get(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher)
           .StartNew<IEnumerable<Foo>>(() => FindData(value))
           .ContinueWith(
               task =>
               {
                   this.foundData.Clear();
                   this.foundData.AddRange(task.Result);
               },
               TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

The `WorkItem` class could expose the properties on the `Task` class to the UI, or it could be extended to encapsulate a `CancellationToken` to support cancellation in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet and detailed explanation. Seems like I have reinvented the wheel (again). But my main problem is that I also want to display pending operations/tasks/WorkItems in the StatusBar of the Window. For that to work I need to find the one and only WorkQueue of the Window in which the Command has been triggered.

Comment: @Korexio: you can add a helper class to encapsulate starting new tasks and use that to track them. Then borrowing from the Task framework you can use it to remove finished items. A bit more work is required to support handling the different statuses of tasks, but that would be another question. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I got the question right, but I feel that using buil in [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) would solve your problem and you do not need implementing `WorkQueue` manually since Dispatcher implements  such a queue for you and able dispatching "worker items" to the UI/any thred using predefined set of priorities. You can execute an operation either synchronously or asynchronously using `Dispatcher.Invoke()` or `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`

Useful links:

- MSDN Magazine: [WPF Threads, Build More Responsive Apps With The Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)

Comment: Using a `Dispatcher` would eliminate my `WorkQueue` class - but still I'd have to find the appropriate `Dispatcher` when I want to add a new `WorkQueueItem`. Also, if I want to visualize the pending items I'l have to create a ViewModel for the `Dispatcher` and use the Hooks to keep my ViewModel and the `Dispatcher` in sync. Are Dispatchers really used to dispatch work to background threads?

Comment: @Korexio: the dispatcher marshals work onto the UI thread. This gets around WPF thread-origin restrictions when working with controls, binding, etc.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Ok, that's what I always use it for. My Problem is that I want to dispatch to a background worker. I've no cross-thread problems at all, I just don't know how to associate a background thread with a window so that all Commands/WorkItems in the Window are dispatched to this background worker. The only way I found so far is to pass a reference to the thread to each ViewModel I create/display in the window...